# ExoPlayer live stream freezes on Askey Android TV box, audio continues

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

On play-out of some of our own DASH+widevine protected live streams, the video freezes after just a few seconds on an Askey Android TV box (Android 9) while audio continues. I also see video chunks still being fetched. 
The same streams play successfully on every other Android device we used so far.

After trying several ExoPlayer versions (v2.7.3, v2.9.x), I integrated the play-out code in ExoPlayer's demo player on github (v2.10.5). Here the same problem occurs: video freezes, audio continues.

As other live streams work without issues on the Askey AndroidTV box, the conclusion is probably that the stream's config somehow triggers this issue. But stream config is the same for working/failing streams, and the player logs don't show any clue on why it happens. Except maybe for this error that appears constantly, also when the player is not active:

```
E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vaudio.debug.search"
W HwBinder:3034_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:285045): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13267 scontext=u:r:hal_audio_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Below is the log of a play-out with video freeze. The freeze happens just after timelineChanged's timestamp 4.34.

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@87575b6
I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init d420716 [ExoPlayerLib/2.10.5] [Android TV Box, askey, 28]
D/EventLogger: state [0.01, 0.00, window=0, true, BUFFERING]
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/EventLogger: surfaceSizeChanged [0.09, 0.00, window=0, 1920, 1080]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [0.15, 3.99, window=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=PREPARED
      period [?]
      window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: mediaPeriodCreated [0.15, 3.99, window=0, period=0]
    loading [0.15, 3.99, window=0, period=0, true]
    decoderEnabled [0.15, 3.99, window=0, period=0, video]
D/EventLogger: decoderEnabled [0.16, 3.99, window=0, period=0, audio]
D/EventLogger: tracksChanged [0.16, 3.99, window=0, period=0, 
D/EventLogger:   Renderer:0 [
        Group:0, adaptive_supported=YES [
D/EventLogger:       [X] Track:0, id=dzGAGgaf, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=400000, codecs=avc1.42e00d, res=400x224, fps=25.0, supported=YES
          [X] Track:1, id=dzEANQyf, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=800000, codecs=avc1.4d401e, res=640x360, fps=25.0, supported=YES
D/EventLogger:       [X] Track:2, id=dzHgyBCf, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=1100000, codecs=avc1.4d401e, res=704x396, fps=25.0, supported=YES
          [X] Track:3, id=dzEAahif, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=1600000, codecs=avc1.4d401f, res=1024x576, fps=25.0, supported=YES
        ]
      ]
      Renderer:1 [
        Group:0, adaptive_supported=N/A [
          [X] Track:0, id=dyHiAZ8., mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=128000, codecs=mp4a.40.2, channels=2, sample_rate=48000, language=nl, supported=YES
        ]
      ]
    ]
D/EventLogger: mediaPeriodReadingStarted [0.18, 3.99, window=0, period=0]
D/EventLogger: downstreamFormatChanged [0.26, 3.99, window=0, period=0, id=dzEAahif, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=1600000, codecs=avc1.4d401f, res=1024x576, fps=25.0]
D/EventLogger: downstreamFormatChanged [0.27, 3.99, window=0, period=0, id=dyHiAZ8., mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=128000, codecs=mp4a.40.2, channels=2, sample_rate=48000, language=nl]
D/EventLogger: drmSessionAcquired [0.39, 3.99, window=0, period=0]
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd4205808 disconnect failed
D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xd1c85008, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome.secure] setting surface generation to 6428686
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xd1c85008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
    connecting to surface 0xd1c85008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::getComponentRole isEncoder :0 mime:video/avc 
V/AVUtils: AVUtils::getComponentRole
E/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome.secure] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -2147483648
I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::isAudioExtendFormat input = video/avc
I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xd1c85008, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
    connecting to surface 0xd1c85008, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0xd1c85008 for 1024x576, color 0x11, rotation 0, usage 0x406933
D/EventLogger: decoderInitialized [0.65, 3.99, window=0, period=0, video, OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome.secure]
D/EventLogger: decoderInputFormatChanged [0.65, 3.99, window=0, period=0, video, id=dzEAahif, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=1600000, codecs=avc1.4d401f, res=1024x576, fps=25.0]
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::getComponentRole isEncoder :0 mime:audio/mp4a-latm 
V/AVUtils: AVUtils::getComponentRole
I/AmAVUtils: AmAVUtils::isAudioExtendFormat input = audio/mp4a-latm
I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec: codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
D/EventLogger: decoderInitialized [0.89, 3.99, window=0, period=0, audio, OMX.google.aac.decoder]
D/EventLogger: decoderInputFormatChanged [0.89, 3.99, window=0, period=0, audio, id=dyHiAZ8., mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=128000, codecs=mp4a.40.2, channels=2, sample_rate=48000, language=nl]
D/EventLogger: drmKeysLoaded [3.40, 3.99, window=0, period=0]
D/EventLogger: videoSizeChanged [3.50, 3.99, window=0, period=0, 1024, 576]
D/EventLogger: renderedFirstFrame [3.52, 3.99, window=0, period=0, Surface(name=null)/@0xcb34ae4]
D/EventLogger: audioSessionId [3.53, 3.99, window=0, period=0, 465]
D/EventLogger: state [3.55, 3.99, window=0, period=0, true, READY]
D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 2143457176437 < limitNs: 2143461518478 < mStartNs: 2143503518478
D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 2143457176437 < limitNs: 2143461518478 < mStartNs: 2143503518478
D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 2143457176437 < limitNs: 2143461518478 < mStartNs: 2143503518478
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [3.63, 0.00, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [4.34, 0.66, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [6.76, 1.08, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [8.44, 0.77, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.99, true, true]
D/EventLogger: ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [10.51, 0.83, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
D/EventLogger:   window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [12.15, 0.47, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
D/EventLogger: ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [14.19, 0.50, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [16.14, 0.46, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
D/EventLogger:   window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [18.17, 0.49, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [20.14, 0.45, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
```

The stream has 4 video tracks:

- 400x224, 0.40 Mbps
- 600x360, 0.80 Mbps
- 704x396, 1.10 Mbps
- 1024x576, 1.60 Mbps

The freeze issue occurs on all tracks, except for the 0.40Mpbs. Here the video continues, but very choppy. In this case logs show frames being dropped:

```
D/EventLogger: state [773.80, -4.02, window=0, period=0, true, READY]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [775.48, -4.45, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
D/EventLogger:   window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: droppedFrames [776.74, -3.19, window=0, period=0, 50]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [777.49, -4.45, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
      window [29.99, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [779.49, -4.46, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
      period [?]
D/EventLogger:   window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
D/EventLogger: droppedFrames [779.90, -4.03, window=0, period=0, 50]
D/EventLogger: timelineChanged [781.48, -4.47, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
D/EventLogger:   period [?]
      window [29.98, true, true]
    ]
```

Finally, here is a manifest of the freezing stream:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Created with VSPP Streamer version 5.2.4.2 build 95193 context 3374162112732519956-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" xmlns:mspr="urn:microsoft:playready" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="dynamic" availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" publishTime="2019-10-16T09:04:33Z" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT30S" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT2S" minBufferTime="PT12S">
    <Period id="1" start="PT0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="1" group="1" bitstreamSwitching="true" segmentAlignment="true" contentType="video" mimeType="video/mp4" maxWidth="1024" maxHeight="576" par="16:9" maxFrameRate="25" startWithSAP="1">
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95" value="MSPR 2.0">
                <mspr:pro>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</mspr:pro>
                <cenc:pssh>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</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed">
                <cenc:pssh>AAAAY3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAAEMIARIQ6cpo1Zp7Saap6x+EIaxU4hoLcGFjZXRlbGVuZXQiIGU5Y2E2OGQ1OWE3YjQ5YTZhOWViMWY4NDIxYWM1NGUy</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="10000000" media="S!d2ELREFTSF9IRDEwODASAlT-....ARYEnw__/QualityLevels($Bandwidth$)/Fragments(video=$Time$)" initialization="S!d2ELREFTSF9IRDEwODASAlT-....ARYEnw__/QualityLevels($Bandwidth$)/Fragments(video=Init)">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="15712166312942690" d="20000000" r="14"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
            <Representation id="dzGAGgaf" bandwidth="400000" codecs="avc1.42e00d" width="400" height="224" frameRate="25" sar="1:1"/>
            <Representation id="dzEANQyf" bandwidth="800000" codecs="avc1.4d401e" width="640" height="360" frameRate="25" sar="1:1"/>
            <Representation id="dzHgyBCf" bandwidth="1100000" codecs="avc1.4d401e" width="704" height="396" frameRate="25" sar="1:1"/>
            <Representation id="dzEAahif" bandwidth="1600000" codecs="avc1.4d401f" width="1024" height="576" frameRate="25" sar="1:1"/>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="2" group="2" bitstreamSwitching="true" segmentAlignment="true" contentType="audio" mimeType="audio/mp4" lang="dut">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95" value="MSPR 2.0">
                <mspr:pro>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</mspr:pro>
                <cenc:pssh>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</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed">
                <cenc:pssh>AAAAY3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAAEMIARIQ6cpo1Zp7Saap6x+EIaxU4hoLcGFjZXRlbGVuZXQiIGU5Y2E2OGQ1OWE3YjQ5YTZhOWViMWY4NDIxYWM1NGUy</cenc:pssh>
            </ContentProtection>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="48000" media="S!d2ELREFTSF9IRDEwODASAlT-....ARYEnw__/QualityLevels($Bandwidth$)/Fragments(audio_482_dut=$Time$)" initialization="S!d2ELREFTSF9IRDEwODASAlT-....ARYEnw__/QualityLevels($Bandwidth$)/Fragments(audio_482_dut=Init)">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="75418398302636" d="96256" r="1"/>
                    <S d="95232"/>
                    <S d="96256" r="2"/>
                    <S d="95232"/>
                    <S d="96256" r="2"/>
                    <S d="95232"/>
                    <S d="96256" r="2"/>
                    <S d="95232"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
            <Representation id="dyHiAZ8." bandwidth="128000" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="48000"/>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

So how should I proceed with investigating this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the video codec "OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome.secure" is the cause. Disabling it in ExoPlayer solves the issue.

Comment: How did you disable it and how this can be done with standard UI component VideoView which is using Android Media Player?

Comment: I made a custom MediaCodecSelector which filters out the problematic codec: https://github.com/tadaam-tv/react-native-video/blob/master/android-exoplayer/src/main/java/com/brentvatne/exoplayer/BlackListMediaCodecSelector.java
The selector is then configured in the DefaultRenderersFactory in ReactExoplayerView.